# How can you have Bootstrap responsiveness based on screen ratio instead of screen resolution in pixel?

Tags: html, css, layout, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to have two columns stacked into one column when the height of view port is larger than the width of the view port. As far as I know `col-xx-xx` is based on the screen resolution in pixel. I have tried `col-sm-6 col-xs-12` for both cells, but that is not the solution.

What is the solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question in Reddit here, https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/6799m7/how_can_you_have_bootstrap_responsiveness_based/.

Basically the solution is to merge the view based on `landscape` or `portrait`.

```
@media screen and (orientation: portrait){
    //css
}
@media screen and (orientation: landscape){
    //css    
}
```